# Find pdf margin using itext api, sometimes the result is wrong

Tags: itext

I am using itext api in java to develop my project. I have some problems about finding right margin, as you can see from my picture:

[The right margin of page is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtYs.png)

[While this one is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTIZk.png)

I used the code from official website, and didn't change anything developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15

I don't understand why I get this result... :/

Comment: I meant, "and didn't change anything. this is the link I refer: developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15" Sorry it's my first time use this, I dunno how to edit the text.

Comment: You  edit the text by clicking the "edit" link. Sorry if that sounds too obvious. It's below your question.

Comment: Most likely in your *wrong* case there is some invisible or off-screen content which iText also takes into account. For a detailed analysis please share the PDF in question.